# BytesIO stream to Numpy arrays? (Picamera)

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, stream

I'm using Picamera with the Raspberry Pi to take pictures and then analyze the differences between them. I'm using the following code to capture to a BytesIO stream and then read that into a Numpy array (borrowed from [this guide](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.6/recipes1.html#capturing-to-an-opencv-object)):

```
stream = io.BytesIO()
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (100, 60)
    camera.framerate = 30
    while not done:
        camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg', use_video_port=True)
        if previousData == None:
            previousData = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8), 1)
            previousData = previousData[:, :, ::-1]
        else:
            timeStartNumpy = time.time()
            currentData = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8), 1)
            currentData = previousData[:, :, ::-1]
            ....(omitted analysis code)....
            previousData = currentData
```

The analysis code works as it should, except it keeps using the same frame repeatedly. I'm assuming that must be a problem with the way I'm reading from the stream, but I'm not experienced enough in Python to know how to change it. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `else` branch you are assigning the current captured frame to the name `currentDate` just to replace this in the next line with the `previousData`.  So the captured frame from the line before is lost as no name or other reference points to it any more.  Just delete this second assignment.

Comment: I neglected to mention the functionality of that line. It comes after the individual frames are analyzed, but the `currentData` is needed for the next analysis to compare against. So we replace the `previousData` with the image in `currentData`, and then take a new image to be the `currentData`. This process continues until the window is closed (done = true).

Comment: The problematic line is _before_ the omitted part not after it and it is clearly the problem in that code because its the reason the code never processes any captured frame except the first one. The line doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Oh. Wow. That's a huge blunder on my part. I should probably read my own code a bit closer.